# How to batch-convert Dual Fisheye Ricoh Theta 360 Movies into Equirectangular Videos?

Tags: command-line, encoding, video-editing

How can I batch-convert and blend multiple Dual Fisheye Ricoh Theta 360 Degree MP4 Movies into Equirectangular Videos for upload to YouTube or use in Adobe Premiere and Final Cut Pro?

Answer (score 2):

The "Ricoh Theta" contains a tool to convert videos via command line. This is useful if you want to batch convert many videos at the same time. Just use this command for each file you like to convert:

```
"/Applications/RICOH THETA.app/Contents/Resources/tools/dualfishblender/osx/DualfishBlender_app.app/Contents/MacOS/DualfishBlender_app" <sourcefilename>.MP4 <destinationfilename>.MP4
```

For example, if you like to convert a number of files, copy paste the lines with all the filenames into your terminal:

```
"/Applications/RICOH THETA.app/Contents/Resources/tools/dualfishblender/osx/DualfishBlender_app.app/Contents/MacOS/DualfishBlender_app" R0010901.MP4 R0010901_er.MP4 & 
"/Applications/RICOH THETA.app/Contents/Resources/tools/dualfishblender/osx/DualfishBlender_app.app/Contents/MacOS/DualfishBlender_app" R0010902.MP4 R0010902_er.MP4 & 
"/Applications/RICOH THETA.app/Contents/Resources/tools/dualfishblender/osx/DualfishBlender_app.app/Contents/MacOS/DualfishBlender_app" R0010903.MP4 R0010903_er.MP4 &
```

I put it in the background using the & symbol so I can run them in parallel within one terminal window.

Comment: Your example only seems to convert one file. Also, why run it in the background?

Comment: @nohillside yes, it needs one line per file. I'm running them in the background so I can process them in parallel. I've updated the above post. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Wouldn’t a `for` loop work better for batch conversion?

Comment: @nohillside I guess there are an infinite amount of better or other solutions, but this one is the one I happen know. Perhaps you can answer with your solution using a `for` loop? I'd definitely be interested, too.